# Очистка string от ненужнных char

Tags: c#

Подскажите хороший способ очистить string от ненужных char.

Найти эти ненужные символы и удалить из строки.

По сути мне нужны только a-z A-Z 0-9 и может быть ещё какие то символыю например дефис `-`.

Пока приходит в голову, создать только список подходящих мне char и каждый символ в строке перебирать через этот список и либо удалять из строки, либо оставлять.

Ещё, у той же структуры char есть различне методы Is и можно наверно их использовать.

Как лучше сделать и чтобы быстрее работало ?

Comment: Похоже на типовую задачу для *регулярных выражений*.

Comment: Для скорости см. StringBuilder

Comment: @CrazyElf ну т.е. не использовать Char.IsLetterOrDigit и что то ещё, а просто проверять char на соответствие шаблона регулярного выражения ?

Comment: @Vipz Регулярками можно не только проверять соответствие строки, но и искать нужные символы в строке. Найти нужные, остальные пропустить. Но можно конечно и как вы описали.

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new(text.Length); foreach (char c in text) if (char.IsDigit(c) || (c => 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) sb.Append(c); return sb.ToString();` А с чем именно проблема? `IsLetterOrDigit` вернет `true` даже для А-Я и других букв юникода, так что он не подходит под условие.

Comment: @aepot проблемы собственно и нет, я бы перебирал по List<char>, но хотелось бы лучшее решение, такак объём большой и ежедневный. По `IsLetterOrDigit` спасибо за замечание, я не протестил и начал использовать его)

Comment: @aepot правильно ли я понял что тут идёт сверка по номеру больше или равно ? `(c => 'A' && c <= 'Z')`

Comment: Какая версия дотнета используется? Если последняя, седьмая, то юзайте регулярки без бектрекинга и с кодогенерацией. Но лучше всё же потестить с помощью Benchmark.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пока 6, но вас понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Vipz а разве не очевидно? В принципе ничего быстрее этого я придумать не могу, ну если только на векторах. Любая регулярка по идее будет медленнее.

Comment: @aepot Понял вас, спасибо!

Comment: `List<char>` - если нужна скорость, нельзя списки использовать, используйте исходный `string` или массив `char[]`.

Comment: В .NET 7 появились новые методы [IsAsciiLetter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isasciiletter?view=net-7.0) и прочие `IsAscii*`

Comment: Вот, да `Char.IsAsciiLetterOrDigit` из .NET 7 тоже подойдет.

Comment: @aepot а как например проверить ещё `'-'` лучше в вашей конструкции ? Добавить `||  c == '-'` или как то ещё ?

Comment: Верно, просто добавить сравнение к условию.

Comment: @aepot а если доп. символов будет достаточно много чтобы их перечилять в `if`, то уже `List<char> chars` ? `|| chars.Contains(c)` ?

Comment: @Vipz не используйте `List` в высокопроизводительных местах кода. Он медленнее по всем параметрам, чем массив. `Array.IndexOf(array, c) >= 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение для .NET 7

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("HelloWorld", 10000000)); // 100M символов
    Console.WriteLine(text.Length);
    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine(IsAsciiString(text));
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static bool IsAsciiString(ReadOnlySpan<char> text)
{
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (!char.IsAsciiLetterOrDigit(c))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

В отладке показывает

```
100000000
True
00:00:00.5075348
```

В релизе

```
100000000
True
00:00:00.1745654
```

А надо ли быстрее? 200 мегабайт данных за 0,1 секунды.

Теперь почистим строку

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Hello World!", 10000000)); // 120M символов

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Console.WriteLine(text.Length);
    string clean = CleanUpText(text);
    Console.WriteLine(clean.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string CleanUpText(ReadOnlySpan<char> text)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(text.Length < 32 ? text.Length : text.Length / 2);
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (char.IsAsciiLetterOrDigit(c))
            sb.Append(c);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

В отладке

```
120000000
100000000
00:00:00.9601710
```

в релизе

```
120000000
100000000
00:00:00.3722909
```

Быстрее только на векторах. Честно говоря, не особо верю в регулярки в таких примитивных задачах, хотя не исключаю, что векторизованная регулярка может оказаться внезапно быстрее кода, приведенного выше. В .NET 7 их сильно ускорили, и при грамотном использовании можно получить прекрасный результат. Вопрос в том, насколько быстро вам это надо, достаточно того что выше, или же нет.

Answer (score 4):

```
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Regex rgx = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
            Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch(args[0]));
            Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace(args[0], ""));
        }
```

В конструктор регулярного выражения нужно включить все разрешённые символы (в данном случае a-z, A-Z и 0-9). IsMatch показывает, есть ли в строке нежелательные символы, а Replace удаляет их.

Так будет лучше. А нужно ли быстрее? Если это какое-то разовое действие, то быстрее не нужно, а если, скажем, требуется обрабатывать миллионы строк, то нужно отказаться от использования регулярных выражений в пользу работы с символами простыми циклами for (не foreach).

Comment: Нет, не разово, миллионы xD

Comment: В последней версии дотнета [регулярки](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/regular-expression-improvements-in-dotnet-7/) векторизованы до предела. Побить их производительность простыми циклами будет очень сложно... / Добавить опцию `RegexOptions.NonBacktracking`, а также использовать [GeneratedRegex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-source-generators) и циклы будут глотать пыль.

Comment: Нужно сделать, протестировать и выбрать лучший вариант